# Adobe Reader program icon and PDF icons don't appear in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Adobe PDF icon disappeared?](https://superuser.com/questions/127857/adobe-pdf-icon-disappeared)

Icons for the Adobe Reader (in the Start menu) program and *.pdf icons don't appear. The only thing is a generic blank icon instead. I tried reinstalling, but it didn't work.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you by any chance run the installer 'as administrator'? Don't!

Comment: By running the installer as admin it causes the problem? How weird.

Comment: well, this will install the program and file associations for the built-in (hidden) Administrator account, not for your user account.

Comment: If you double-click on a PDF file, does it open in Adobe Reader? If not, right-click on the file and set the default program for opening PDFs to Adobe Reader.